# How to deal with virtual address when trying to get memory access pattern statistics?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, cpu, intel

I'm working on a project that needs to get statistics of memory access pattern of a program. (by memory access pattern, I mean a accessing probability distribution of different regions of memory)

I used Intel Pintool and have got the address of all instructions(Instruction Pointer) and the all memory addresses that is accessed in these instructions. The statistics are like this:
in the format of:

```
fprintf(trace,"%p: R/W %p\n", ip, addr); //IP Read/Write addr

0x7f096b04e2d3: W 0x7fff17713f68
0x7f096b051a70: W 0x7fff17713f60
0x7f096b051a74: W 0x7fff17713f58
0x7f096b051a76: W 0x7fff17713f50
0x7f096b051a78: W 0x7fff17713f48
0x7f096b051a7a: W 0x7fff17713f40
0x7f096b051a7c: W 0x7fff17713f38
0x7f096b051a8f: R 0x7f096b26fe70
0x7f096b051a96: W 0x7f096b26fc98
0x7f096b051aa7: R 0x7f096b270000
```

The questions is, in the perspective of CPU, these address are all Virtual Addr, which cannot be used if I want to get the physical memory access pattern.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to knowing probability of accessing different regions of physical RAM? One 4K page of physical RAM is the same as any other.

Comment: Do you want to say that every page is 4 KByte, an memory is accessed in the unit of pages? That doesn't matter. If I can get the accessing frequency/probability distribution of all pages, that will also solve my problem.

Comment: I'm saying the information you're looking for isn't very interesting or useful. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to do a simulation on cache-isolation. I need to know how cache access pattern will be like for programs. Then I can utilize the access pattern in the simulation to get some more realistic statistics on cache performance. I think if I get accessing frequency/probability distribution of all page will work fine, since the performance will not change in a whole.

Comment: Modern Intel processors have a L1 micro-operation cache whose behaviour isn't easy to model. Even those processors with normal L1 caches support things like prefetching, branch prediction, speculative execution and on some models hyperthreading, so the memory access pattern can be much different than that implied by the instructions actually executed.  Also L1 cache way sizes are 4K or a few powers of two bigger, so all or most of the bits that affect cache behaviour are in the same for both linear and physical addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that in Pin, but I don't think so. You might want to check out [pagemap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt). This should at least give you a resource to translate the virtual addresses to physical addresses although you'll have to process it a little. From the documentation:

> The general procedure for using pagemap to find out about a process'
>   memory usage goes like this:
>
> 1. Read /proc/pid/maps to determine which parts of the memory space are
>      mapped to what.
> 2. Select the maps you are interested in -- all of them, or a particular
>      library, or the stack or the heap, etc.
> 3. Open /proc/pid/pagemap and seek to the pages you would like to examine.
> 4. Read a u64 for each page from pagemap.
> 5. Open /proc/kpagecount and/or /proc/kpageflags.  For each PFN you just
>      read, seek to that entry in the file, and read the data you want.